# jasmine.clock().tick() does not work with $timeout and debounce, but works fine with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, leaflet, lodash

Below I have 3 functions that do exactly the same thing. Each one uses a different way of calling `setTimeout`, `delay1()` uses `setTimeout` directly, `delay2()` uses angularjs `$timeout` and `delay3()` uses lodash `debounce`. They all work fine.

The problems occurs when I test using Jasmine. `setTimeout` works fine with the `jasmine.clock().tick()` method, but `$timeout` and `debounce` don't

I am interested in getting debounce working with Jasmine. I know I can use `$timeout.flush()` with angularjs but `$timeout` and `setTimeout` give me problems elsewhere in my code where I am using it with leaflet maps. debounce works nicely with leaflet.

I have created a plunker here: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BCGoTdnJ0mrMYVPljGhr?p=preview) where you will see the `$timeout` and debounce tests not passing while the setTimeout test passes.

Is there a way I can work around this problem? Thanks

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.delayed1 = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $scope.name = "Hello world by setTimeout";
    },500)
  }
  $scope.delayed2 = function(){
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.name = "Hello world by $timeout";
    },500)
  }
  $scope.delayed3 = function(){
    _.debounce(function(){
      $scope.name = "Hello world by debounce";
    },500)
  }
});
```

spec

```
describe('Testing a Hello World controller', function() {
  var $scope = null;
  var ctrl = null;

  //you need to indicate your module in a test
  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
  }));

  it('should say hallo to the World', function() {
    expect($scope.name).toEqual('World');
  });
  it('should say Hello world by setTimeout', function() {
    jasmine.clock().install();
    $scope.delayed1();
    jasmine.clock().tick(600);
    expect($scope.name).toEqual('Hello world by setTimeout');
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();

  });
  it('should say Hello world by timeout', function() {
    jasmine.clock().install();
    $scope.delayed2();
    jasmine.clock().tick(600);
    expect($scope.name).toEqual('Hello world by timeout');
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();

  }); 
  it('should say Hello world by debouce', function() {
    jasmine.clock().install();
    $scope.delayed3();
    jasmine.clock().tick(600);
    expect($scope.name).toEqual('Hello world by debouce');
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();

  }); 
});
```

Comment: any conclusion on this?

Comment: No, not yet. Anybody?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The clock in Jasmine will only work if you're testing `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` functions directly as it just mocks those functions specifically to run synchronously. I believe there's a pull request for Jasmine to mock the Date object, which would allow for testing functions like `_.debounce()` without mocking it, but I don't remember if that was merged in or not.

To test `_.debounce()` you'll have to mock it to run synchronously, preferably as a spy or you can just override the function. Here's what I've found to work for me:

```
spyOn(_, 'debounce').and.callFake(function (func) {
    return function () {
        func.apply(this, arguments);
    };
});
```

Now calls to `_.debounce()` will run synchronously and tests should complete successfully. Of course you'll still have to use `$timeout.flush()`.

I updated your plunker with these changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/KXmwcf1faUNf8nlqPeyd

Comment: Thanks for the work around Sedushi. I'll definitely keep this trick in mind

Comment: Awesome, was banging my head before but finally this one worked.

Comment: Great solution! can I add some syntactic sugar though: `spyOn(_, 'debounce').and.callFake(_.identity);`

Comment: There's an edge case issue here. If you have a watch with a debounced function, and mock the debounce in this way, then when you call the $scope.$apply() required to trigger the watcher, in the case that there's a $scope.$apply() in the debounced function then we'll get an error as we'll still be in the digest cycle that triggered it.

I'm thinking that ideally we'd do better to mock it with a function that immediately resolves a timeout but I haven't got it working yet. :/

What a nuisance!

Comment: Clever solution +1

Answer (score 3):

The debounce function from `lodash` uses the `Date` object. You mock the `Date` object using `jasmine` like this:

```
jasmine.clock().install();
jasmine.clock().mockDate();

jasmine.clock().tick(1000); // trigger the debounce
```

Source: https://jasmine.github.io/2.9/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_Date

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @JDWardle's answer you maye also want to create a spy for the debounce cancel method.

```
spyOn(_, 'debounce').and.callFake(function (func) {
    var mockDebounce = function () {
        func.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    mockDebounce.cancel = jasmine.createSpy('cancel');
    return mockDebounce;
});
```