# Asserting number of http calls in recursive $timeout in AngularJS unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, recursion, timeout

I currently have a recursive function that polls a webpage and retries on a non 200 response:

```
app.service('PingService', function($q, $http, $timeout) {

var timer = null;
var deferred = $q.defer();

function ping() {

    var url = 'http://www.google.com';

    function successCallback() {
        deferred.resolve();
    }

    function retry(accountName) {
        timer = $timeout(ping, 2000);
    }

    $http.get(url).success(successCallback).error(retry);
}

return {
    pingUrl: function() {
        ping();
        return defer.promise;
    }
}
```

To test this implementation, I currently have the following test in jasmine:

```
it('should retry on non 200 response', function() {  
    $httpBackend.whenGET('http://www.google.com').respond(504);

    PingService.pingUrl();

    $httpBackend.flush();

    $timeout.flush(4001);
    $httpBackend.flush(2);
 }
```

Unfortunately, this fails to pass because there only seems to be 1 http request in the queue and not the 2 that I was expecting for the amount of elapsed time.

Is there anyway for me to unit test the number of http retries made over a period of time with a recursive function that uses $timeout?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what you're trying to do with the $timeout.flush() there? I would use jasmine's built in clock functionality to tick forward the required amount of time.

Comment: I'm calling $timeout.flush() to flush the deferreds in the $timeout service that've defined in my implementation. I had a look at Jasmine clock's functionality and ticking the time over still presents me with the same problem because it only works with setInterval and setTimeout, not with AngularJS's $timeout service - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077376/jasmine-clock-tick-does-not-work-with-timeout-and-debounce-but-works-fine